# duration of an insert and an update sqlite command

Tags: android, sqlite, time, duration

is 180ms normal for one 
 
`db.update("table", values, "_id" + "=" + arg3, null);` command ?
and 70ms for one 
`db.insert("table", null, values);` command ?
Nexus S , Android 4

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming that your database operation involves writing to flash memory. And if the next question is how to get 100 of your database operations to perform faster than 100 * 180 ms, please use transactions: [Android SQLite database: slow insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion)