# Most efficient way to INSERT SQLite data

Tags: android, sqlite

On first install, my app has to cache data it gets from the network, and insert rows into an SQLite database. I end up with around 700 inserts, which takes at least 15 seconds. Currently my logic is as follows (pseudo):

```
ScrollThroughAllObjects(){
    if(objectDoesNotExist){
        cacheObject();
    }
}

cacheObject(Object ob){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, ob.getId);
    // add lots more values
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
}
```

Is there a more efficient, quicker, way for me to handle this insert?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SQLite database: slow insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion)

Answer (score 6):

Perform your record insertion using **SQLite Transaction**. It will amazingly speed up the entire process; because when you perform single insertion (one at a time) SQLite treats each insertion as a transaction and needs to create *Journal-file* for each execution (which takes time). However, when you bind all your add/edit/delete queries to a single transaction then only one Journal file is created throughout the end of transaction causing SQLite to execute queries rapidly.

Comment: Great that took the whole thing down to less than 3 seconds, thanks.

Comment: optimization does offer great effects :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the entire operation in a transaction. This alone will give you a huge speed increase, as well as giving you the benefits of transactional behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `bulkInsert` method. You can get the code from [SQLiteContentProvider](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3_r1/com/android/apps/tag/provider/SQLiteContentProvider.java). Modify it for your need.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating and connecting to a database**

First import android.databse.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase into your application. Then use the openOrCreateDatabase() method to create or connect to a database. [Sqlite documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

onCreate() – These is where we need to write create table statements. This is called when database is created.
onUpgrade() – This method is called when database is upgraded like modifying the table structure, adding constraints to database etc.,

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

**Inserting records**

Android comes with a series of classes that simplify database usage. Use a ContentValues instance to create a series of table field to data matchings that will be passed into an insert() method. Android has created similar methods for updating and deleting records.

The `addContact()` method accepts Contact object as parameter. We need to build ContentValues parameters using Contact object. Once we inserted data in database we need to close the database connection.

```
    // Adding new contact
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone Number

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

See full article for this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/).

Watch this [video](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=117), which is simple define, how to create table and inserting data in to android.

Finally dont miss this,  Android SQLite : Insert, Update, Delete and Display Data([Link](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/02/mysql/android-sqlite-insert-update-delete-and-display-data/)).