# background thread not responding android asynctask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, filesystems

I am trying to traverse all the folders in the file system.
and I want to index all the traversed files.
When I am trying to do the indexing with SQLite db, the app doesn't respond.
What is the way to get it working?

```
  private class StartIndexing extends AsyncTask<File, String, String>{


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(File... params) {
                String indexDone="0";
                File file=params[0];
                indexIn(file);

                indexDone="Async Done";
                return indexDone;
            }

            protected void indexIn(File folder){
                File[] dirs=folder.listFiles();

                for(File val:dirs){

                    if(val.isDirectory()){
                        new StartIndexing().executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,val);

                        count++;
                    }
                    else{
                        DBoperation(val);
                        filecount++;
                    }

                }


            }
```

Comment: Show us the code and log please.

Comment: ok wait... i'll post the code.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing a db insert every time you find a file. Instead, save the info in a data structure, like a List, then dump it to the db when the scan is complete.

Comment: @MikeM. how can we do that?

Comment: @vokilam thnx for the edit

Comment: Create a POJO class with only the file data you need. Create a List of those objects. Instead of calling `DBoperation(val)`, add an instance of your POJO for each file to the List. When it's done scanning, insert the List's data into the db. [Check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328350/how-to-speed-up-large-data-insertion-in-database-sqlite-in-android-application) for tips on inserting large amounts of data.

Comment: I forgot to mention, an `AsyncTask` might not be the best solution if you're traversing a sizable hierarchy, as they are meant for short-lived operations. You might look into `Service`s, specifically `IntentService`s.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logcat it should tell you where the problem occurs.
Make sure the objects you use are not null. For instance, the 'params'.

Another possibility
file.listFiles() will return null if that file is empty, you'll get NPE when try to use it

Comment: code works in emulator so i dont get an error in logcat. but fails on device

Comment: the file system in emulator and device is different, highly possible some files are empty, just my guess

Comment: It wont matter if files are empty.I am just inserting their path into the db.

Comment: It does, File[] dirs=folder.listFiles(); for(File val:dirs){...}, if dirs is null, you'll get null pointer ex

Comment: It will crash, thats your main issue isn't it?

Comment: crashing is my issue. but It wont crash if the directory is null, thats my point.

Comment: I'm just making assumption based on your code. If you're not doing any exception catching there, chances are yes for(file : <null>) will definitely crash the app

Comment: No. It wont crash. The loop will only loop until there are files in the array. If the array comes out to be empty then it wont loop and execute the remaining code.