# Save 5000 object in my sql lite data base

Tags: android, sqlite

I am downloading a json file that countain 5000 objects. This is done in 10 seconds, but when i am trying to save all those elements in my database, that take a huge time, more than 5 minutes.

Did any one face this problem? any explanation, why it take all this time? How can i fix this problem?

I used this answer to fix my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3501572/833219

Comment: Make sure you download the file completely first, then insert to database. Otherwise you may be downloading the same json file over and over before every insert.

Comment: I'm assuming that you open database, insert an item and close it... use bulk insert...

Comment: You should try to insert as many items as possible under one transaction. Inserting one item in one transaction is not efficient.

Comment: Depends on android version, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html might give improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use transactions to do multiple inserts.
You can only do very few commits per second but lots of inserts per transaction.

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19