# Android Sqlite Performance

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I have been doing some experiments to measure sqlite performance on android. I was disappointed a little bit with the results. What i did was inserting 10.000  queries to table and **it took 130-140 seconds** *but with these conditions*;

**1.** Samsung galaxy s3 in power saving mode

**2.** Inserted data(or class)has 3 strings and one float(real for sqlite)

**3.** Insert event is being done in asynctask.

**4.** In asynctask, i am showing a progress dialog with passed timer text in it (System.currentTimeMillis - seconds etc blala)

```
class AddStudentsTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void>
{
    ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    int max = 10000;
    Student s;
    long seconds = System.currentTimeMillis();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        prgDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        prgDialog.setMessage(seconds+"");
        prgDialog.setMax(max);
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
        prgDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate();
        prgDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
        sList.add(s);
        String s = (System.currentTimeMillis()-seconds)/100+"";
        if(s.length()>2)
            s = s.substring(0,s.length()-1) + "." + s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        else if(s.length() == 2)
            s = s.charAt(0) + "." + s.charAt(1);
        prgDialog.setMessage(s + " seconds passed.");

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        for(int a = 0;a< max; a++ )
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            s = new Student();

            s.setGpa(r.nextFloat()*4);
            s.setLastName("asdasd");
            s.setFirstName("Oh My God");
            s.setAddress("1sadasd");
            s.setId(sda.insert(s));
            publishProgress(a);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        prgDialog.dismiss();
        sa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**5.** I am using contentValues with insertOrThrow method in helperdb class.
**THIS IS OLD SLOW CODE**

```
public long insert(Student s)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(StudentHelper.FIRSTNAME,s.getFirstName());
    cv.put(StudentHelper.LASTNAME,s.getLastName());
    cv.put(StudentHelper.ADDRESS,s.getAddress());
    cv.put(StudentHelper.GPA,s.getGpa());
    s.setId(db.insertOrThrow(StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv));
    return s.getId();
}
```

**6.** This task is done in onCreate method of activity.

*So what am i doing wrong here or expecting too much from it? Are these results ok or bad?*

**What can i do to improve my code?**

**EDIT**

So i changed my insert code to this and it reduced to 4.5 seconds!!!

```
public ArrayList<Long> insertMany(ArrayList<Student> stus)
{
    ArrayList<Long> ids = new ArrayList();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO "+StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME+"" +
            "("+StudentHelper.FIRSTNAME+","+StudentHelper.LASTNAME+"," +
            " "+StudentHelper.GPA+") values(?,?,?)";
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();

    for(Student s:stus) {
        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);

        stmt.bindString(1, s.getFirstName());
        stmt.bindString(2, s.getLastName());
        stmt.bindDouble(3, s.getGpa());

        s.setId(stmt.executeInsert());
        ids.add(s.getId());
        stmt.clearBindings();
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    return ids;
}
```

Comment: I don't see `endTransaction` or `setTransactionSuccessful` if you just added `beginTransaction` in your `insert` method then you missed the whole point.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh You are right. I edited my post. Thank you for constructive criticism!!

Comment: Nope, still wrong. You have to do `beginTransaction` and then 10.000 insertions and then `setTransactionSuccessful` and then `endTransaction`. Modify your `AddStudentsTask` for this to work.

Comment: I understand it, yeah you are saying  i am reopening 10k times for insertion. I get it thank you=). I edited post for future problem havers to give them some idea  about usage.

Comment: @M-WaJeEh   I understanded your point but lazy to change what it should be =)) Ok i edited my post, thank you.

Comment: yup this one is perfect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69725/discussion-between-m-wajeeh-and-mert-serimer).

Comment: See this link,perhaps help you     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867973/insert-over-6000-recods-in-sqlite-android

Comment: Shouldn't your db.compileStatement(... Be outside of the for loop? I think you only need to call that once and bind, execute, and clearBindings on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: There is nice performance benchmark on Jason Feinstein's blog: 
https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-insertions-971aff98eef2

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `SQLite transaction` for speed up

Use **BEGIN TRANSACTION** & **END TRANSACTION** for SQLite Optimization

Each SQL statement is enclosed in a new transaction block by SQLite runtime, by default. Sowhen you perform a basic DB operation such as **INSERT**, a transaction block will be created and wrapped around it.

Letting SQLite runtime manage the transaction for you is advisable only if your routine performs only one DB operation on a data set. However, if you are doing  numerous DB operations (say **INSERT** inside for loop), this becomes very expensive, since it requires reopening, writing to, and closing the journal file for each statement.
You may refer

1. [Android SQLite database: slow insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion)
2. http://www.androidcode.ninja/android-sqlite-transaction-tutorial/
3. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/turbocharge-your-sqlite-inserts-on-android/
4. http://www.android-app-market.com/sqlite-optimization-in-android-programming-sqlite-optimization-in-android-apps.html

Comment: above just a link nothing else so will you provide some explanation

Comment: Thank you for answer. It speeded up 20 times lol. it took 7.5 seconds

Comment: I edited my post for future problem havers so they can change their code.

Answer (score 12):

You can use SQL **transactions** in Android like this. It's better to insert multiple rows into the database in larger batches then making single commit (write into SQLlite datafile which is very slow) for every inserted row.

```java
public void insert(List<Student> students)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = sh.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    db.beginTransaction();

    try {
        for (Student s : students) {
            cv.put(StudentHelper.FIRSTNAME,s.getFirstName());
            cv.put(StudentHelper.LASTNAME,s.getLastName());
            cv.put(StudentHelper.ADDRESS,s.getAddress());
            cv.put(StudentHelper.GPA,s.getGpa());

            db.insertOrThrow(StudentHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, cv)
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks you so much for this solution. This really improved the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have so many records and for every record you call `getWritableDatabase()` and then insert it, which is bad for performance.

You need to use transactions. Look at this  question [Android SQLite database: slow insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion). Basically you need to call `beginTransaction()`, do your insertions and then call `setTransactionSuccessful()` preceded by `endTransaction()`. You will be amazed to see how much performance gain you will get with this.