# Should I excute Insert, Delete, Update on my own SQLite DB inside AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver, asynctaskloader

I read many posts telling long operations (like reading DB) should not be excuted on the main Thread.

So far I used `CursorLoader` (for "reading" `ContentResolver`) and`AsynkTaskLoader`(for "reading" my own SQLite DB).

I know to perform `Insert`, `Delete` and `Update` "on" `ContentResolver` I can use `AsyncQueryHandler`.

My question is: what's the best way to execute `Insert`, `Delete` and `Update` on my own SQLite db??

Should I simply execute those operations inside the method `loadInBackground()` of `AsyncTaskLoader`?

Thank you

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` and execute updates in `doInBackground` method.
But, if your updates light and fast you can freely execute them in the UI thread and make your life a bit easier.

Comment: Thank you man :)

Comment: Even slow devices are capable of performing couple of hundreds of simple db operations per second, so there is no point to do single or few operations in the background.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188164/android-sqlite-performance

Answer (score 1):

If your queries are **simple** and it won't make much time to execute then simply you can use it in **main thread** itself.

If you're doing big data process then you have two options.

1. **AsyncTask**:

If you want to update your UI after an operation, you can use **AsyncTask** to do the process in a background thread and pass the result into the main thread. for more info about **AsyncTaksk** click [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

2.**Thread**

If there is no purpose of updating UI after the operation you can simply use **Thread** to do it.

Comment: Thank you man. What is evaluated ad a "big data process" for a mobile?
saving/deleting/updating 100 records? 1.000? 1000.000?

Comment: I won't use main thread if i need to query more than 20 records.

Comment: I don't know the exact numbers. But it's not about numbers, its about execution time.

Comment: Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use background handler thread for your purpose.

```
private Handler mHandler = null;  // global variable
private HandlerThread mHandlerThread = null; // global variable
```

// Create instance inside onCreate() or another place inside your code so it would be called one's. Also you can make it singleton if required but it's not the right way.

```
    mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("HandlerThread");
    mHandlerThread.start();
    mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
```

// perform background operation like :

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       // Do background work here.

                   }
                }, 2000);
```