# How to handle transactions with SQLite and Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, transactions, android-sqlite

I try to include transactions in my application because writing in database is very slow and I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion) and [here](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/12/android-sqlite-transaction-tutorial.html) that transactions are a solution but they are still very confusing to me.

I have `Schedule` objects that contains an object `LineStation`, and I want to write them in database using transactions.

Here, the method `addSchedules` in my class `ScheduleDAO`, that writes all schedules in database. It contains only one transaction.

```
public void addSchedules(ArrayList<Schedule> schedulesList) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.dh.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();

    for (Schedule schedule : schedulesList) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        // insert linestation
        LineStationDAO.getLineStationDAO().addLineStation(schedule.getLineStation());

        values.put(/*...*/);
        /* ... */

        db.insert(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_SCHEDULE, null, values);
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    db.close();
}
```

And this is, the method `addLineStation` in my class `LineStationDAO` that saves the object `LineStation` given. It's called by `addSchedules` and doesn't contain transaction because it is "nested" in the `addSchedules` transaction.

```
public void addLineStation(LineStation lineStation)  {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.dh.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(/*...*/);
    /* ... */

    db.insert(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LINE_STATION, null, values); // database is locked (code 5)
    db.close();
}
```

The `LineStation` insert implies an `SQLiteDatabaseLockedException` (database is locked -code 5).
What I have done wrong, please? Thanks.

Comment: I *think* that is because you get another Database object (`getWriteableDatabase()`), reusing the same instance should fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a database transaction cannot exist across multiple database connections. In the addLineStation method, you are opening a second database connection, when you should be using the one created in addSchedules.

You need to pass the SQLiteDatabase db object down to the addLineStation method like this:

```
LineStationDAO.getLineStationDAO().addLineStation(db, schedule.getLineStation());
```

and change this:

```
public void addLineStation(SQLiteDatabase db, LineStation lineStation)  {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(/*...*/);
    /* ... */

    db.insert(DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LINE_STATION, null, values); // database is no longer locked (code 5)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! SQLiteDatabaseLockedException gone.
I also add a nested transaction to LineStation and it works perfectly!
30 seconds instead of 3 minutes previously!

Comment: No worries. You shouldn't need to add a nested transaction. By having one outer transaction, all the inserts work or they all fail.