# Bulk Insert for cordovaSQLite

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sqlite, cordova

Is there a Bulk insert for cordovaSQLite? 
I have a lot of Data, which I want to save in a sqlite Db.

My code now is

```
var query = "INSERT INTO Card (CardId, CardSetId, FrontText, BackText, ControlType, CardLevel, IsDirty, ChangedAt, Active) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

for (var i = 0; i < cardList.length; i++) {
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [cardList[i].CardId, cardList[i].CardSetId, cardList[i].FrontText, cardList[i].BackText, cardList[i].ControlType, cardList[i].CardLevel, cardList[i].IsDirty, cardList[i].ChangedAt, cardList[i].Active]);
}
```

It works but is very very slow!

When I use this code :

```
var query = "INSERT INTO Card (CardId, CardSetId, FrontText, BackText, ControlType, CardLevel, IsDirty, ChangedAt, Active) VALUES ";
var data = [];
var rowArgs = [];
cardList.forEach(function (card) {
    rowArgs.push("(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    data.push(card.CardId);
    data.push(card.CardSetId);
    console.log(card.CardSetId);
    data.push(card.FrontText);
    data.push(card.BackText);
    data.push(card.ControlType);
    data.push(card.CardLevel);
    data.push(card.IsDirty);
    data.push(card.ChangedAt);
    data.push(card.Active);
});
query += rowArgs.join(", ");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [data]).then(function (res) {
    console.log("inserted");
    }, function(err) {
          console.dir(err);
});
```

Then I get the following error: sqlite3_step failure: NOT NULL constraint failed: Card.CardSetId

But in the data array CardSetId is not empty!

Is there a way to make it faster, or do it with a bulk insert?

Thanks

Comment: I added some indexes to the table and it made it a little bit faster, but not enough... Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [cordova-sqlite-porter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter). Pass it your inserts as a JSON structure using [importJsonToDb()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter#importjsontodb) and it will [optimise the insertion](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter#json-import-optimisations) into the SQLite DB.

The [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter-example) illustrates insertion of 15,000+ records. On a Samsung Galaxy S4, performing this using single SQL insert statements takes around 5 minutes/300 seconds, but the optimised JSON equivalent (using UNION SELECT - [see here for info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009740/777265)) takes around 3 seconds on the same device - 100X faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats would be great, becouse I get the Data anyway in JSON...

Comment: I have to use the sqlite-porter with importSqlToDb(). But now I have problem with single quota or with back slash in the string. Is there a solution for that? Becouse I have to write the sql query like this : "INSERT INTO Artist(Id,Title) VALUES ('1','Fred's ball \ shoe');"; and can not use parameter...

Comment: @user1861065  Can the plugin prevent SQL Injection? I couldn't see stuff getting escaped in the examples...