# Ionic 3 inserting a lot of data

Tags: sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework, insert, ionic3

I have a problem with an ionic3 app I'm been developing.
With my app I conect to a JSON server and download a lot of rows, when I have all rows with a for, in each row call to funcion to insert data.
but I think, my for is faster than insert funcion and show finalice alert before end. this is my code:

```
 private downloadRows()
 {
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
   this.translateService.get('ACTUALIZANDOBARRANCOS').subscribe(
    value => {
    let loadingContent = value; 
    let loader = this.loadingController.create({
    content: loadingContent,
    spinner: "bubbles"
    });  

    this.servicioDownloads.downloadAllRows().then(rows=> {
        this.datosrows= rows;
        loader.present();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.datosrows.length; i++)
        {
          var datos = this.datosrows[i];
          // we are going to insert rows
          this.servicioDataBase.insertRow
          ( datos.indice,
            datos.row1, 
            datos.row2,
            datos.row3, 
            datos.row4, 
            datos.row5,
            datos.row6, 
            datos.row7, 
            datos.row8, 
            datos.row9, 
            datos.row10, 
            //...
            datos.row30
          ).catch(()=>{
            console.log("da error");
          });
        }
        loader.dismiss();
        this.translateService.get('FINALIZADO').subscribe(
              Titulo =>{
                  let titulo = Titulo;

               this.translateService.get('BARRANCOSACTUALIZADOS').subscribe(
                    Descripcion =>{
                      let descripcion = Descripcion;
                      let alerta = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: titulo,
                        subTitle: descripcion,
                        buttons: ['OK']
                      })
                      alerta.present();
                    }
                  );
              }
            );


  }).catch(error=>{
    loader.dismiss();
        this.translateService.get('ERROR').subscribe(
              Titulo =>{
                  let titulo = Titulo;

  this.translateService.get('ERRORDESCARGABARRANCOS').subscribe(
                    Descripcion =>{
                      let descripcion = Descripcion;
                      let alerta = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: titulo,
                        subTitle: descripcion,
                        buttons: ['OK']
                      })
                      alerta.present();
                    }
                  );
              }
        );
  })
});
})
```

}

//This is insert services

```
public insertRow( indice: any, row1: any, row2: any,  row3: any,  row4: any, 
  row5: any,  row6: any,   row7: any,   row8: any,   row9: any,  row10: any, 
  row30: any)
 {    
  let sql = "INSERT INTO TableRows (id,Nombre,Rio,Pais,Comunidad, 
  Zona,Localidad,Interes,Caracter,Cascada_max,Cuerda_max,Desnivel, 
  Longitud, Tiempo_aprox,Tiempo_descenso,Tiempo_retorno,Observaciones, 
  Descripcion_barranco,Periodo_optimo,Caudal,Caudal_filtro,Aproximacion, 
  Retorno,Loc_entrada_barranco,Loc_salida_barranco,Loc_entrada_parking, 
  Loc_salida_parking,Autor,Actualizacion,Idioma,Visible) 
  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  console.log(sql); 
  return this.isReady()
  .then(()=>{
      return this.database.executeSql(sql, 
            [indice,BARRANCO, RIO, PAIS,COMUNIDAD,
              ZONA,LOCALIDAD,INTERES,CARACTER, CASCADA_MAX, 
              CUERDA_MAX,DESNIVEL,LONGITUD,TIEMPO_APROX,
              TIEMPO_DESCENSO,TIEMPO_RETORNO, OBSERVACIONES, 
              DESCRIPCION_BARRANCO,PERIODO_OPTIMO,CAUDAL,
              CAUDAL_FILTRO,APROXIMACION, RETORNO,
              LOC_ENTRADA_BARRANCO,LOC_SALIDA_BARRANCO, 
              LOC_ENTRADA_PARKING, LOC_SALIDA_PARKING, 
              AUTOR,actualización,idioma, visible]);
  }).then((data)=>{
    console.log("El insert devuelve esto " + JSON.stringify(data));
  })        

}
```

Somebody knows how can I do on time, I mean insert when for ends?

thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try using cordova-sqlite-porter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385963/5059916

Comment: Thanks @TomislavStankovic, I going to see it and I will tell you

Comment: @TomislavStankovic it works perfectly, thanks a lot, I used sqlite-porter and works fine and faster! only one think more. when I imported all of data, I went to screen when show all rows, but I cant see this rows after close app and opened again. I use virtualscroll.

Comment: I added it as answer so people can easier see the solution. As for showing data on screen, can you see it at moment after they are inserted? Did data disappear after you close and open app or they have not been displayed at all?

Answer (score 0):

just use async/await in your function, it will allow you call async functions in sequence manner (since [Typescript 2.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-21) you are able to downlevel async/await to ES3/ES5). So solution in your example could look like this:

```
private downloadRows()
{
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
   this.translateService.get('ACTUALIZANDOBARRANCOS').subscribe(
    async value => {
        let loadingContent = value; 
        let loader = this.loadingController.create({
            content: loadingContent,
            spinner: "bubbles"
        });  

        let rows = await this.servicioDownloads.downloadAllRows();
        loader.present();
        for (let datos of rows) {
           // we are going to insert rows
           try {
             await this.servicioDataBase.insertRow
              ( datos.indice,
                datos.row1, 
                datos.row2,
                datos.row3, 
                datos.row4, 
                datos.row5,
                datos.row6, 
                datos.row7, 
                datos.row8, 
                datos.row9, 
                datos.row10, 
                //...
                datos.row30
              );
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        loader.dismiss();
        this.translateService.get('FINALIZADO').subscribe(
              Titulo =>{
                  let titulo = Titulo;

               this.translateService.get('BARRANCOSACTUALIZADOS').subscribe(
                    Descripcion =>{
                      let descripcion = Descripcion;
                      let alerta = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: titulo,
                        subTitle: descripcion,
                        buttons: ['OK']
                      })
                      alerta.present();
                    }
                  );
              }
            );
  }).catch(error=>{
    loader.dismiss();
        this.translateService.get('ERROR').subscribe(
              Titulo =>{
                  let titulo = Titulo;

  this.translateService.get('ERRORDESCARGABARRANCOS').subscribe(
                    Descripcion =>{
                      let descripcion = Descripcion;
                      let alerta = this.alertCtrl.create({
                        title: titulo,
                        subTitle: descripcion,
                        buttons: ['OK']
                      })
                      alerta.present();
                    }
                  );
              }
        );
  })
});
})
```

`await` in for cycle prevents for cycle to finish before insert is actually done.

Answer (score -1):

**[SQLite Porter](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite-porter/)** - This Cordova/Phonegap plugin can be used to import/export to/from a SQLite database using either SQL or JSON.

Installation:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/sqlite-porter
```

Usage:

```
import { SQLitePorter } from '@ionic-native/sqlite-porter';


constructor(private sqlitePorter: SQLitePorter) { }

...

let db = window.openDatabase('Test', '1.0', 'TestDB', 1 * 1024);
// or we can use SQLite plugin
// we will assume that we injected SQLite into this component as sqlite
this.sqlite.create({
  name: 'data.db',
  location: 'default'
})
  .then((db: any) => {
    let dbInstance = db._objectInstance;
    // we can pass db._objectInstance as the database option in all SQLitePorter methods
  });


let sql = 'CREATE TABLE Artist ([Id] PRIMARY KEY, [Title]);' +
           'INSERT INTO Artist(Id,Title) VALUES ("1","Fred");';

this.sqlitePorter.importSqlToDb(db, sql)
  .then(() => console.log('Imported'))
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

> You can try using [cordova-sqlite-porter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter). Pass it your inserts as
>   a JSON structure using [importJsonToDb()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter#importjsontodb) and it will [optimise the
>   insertion](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter#json-import-optimisations) into the SQLite DB.
>
> The [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter-example) illustrates insertion of 15,000+ records. On
>   a Samsung Galaxy S4, performing this using single SQL insert
>   statements takes around 5 minutes/300 seconds, but the optimised JSON
>   equivalent (using UNION SELECT - [see here for info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009740/777265)) takes around
>   3 seconds on the same device - 100X faster. - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35385963/5059916)