# Android: how to insert data faster in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, database-performance, bulkinsert

I'm getting muliple records from webservice and I'm inserting those records in internal database but inserting and updating is taking much time. 
For faster insertion I call the beginTransaction methods of database helper but it is still taking the same time. Please check where I'm making mistake.

```
 VideoEntity videoEntity;  
 for(int i = 0; i < response.body().getCategoryList().size(); i++) {
                   videoEntity = response.body().getCategoryList().get(i);
                    dbHelper.insertChannels(videoEntity);

                }
```

insert method in dbHelper class

```
public void insertChannels(VideoEntity videoEntity) {
    Log.e("inserting channels", "yes");
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELID, videoEntity.getVideoEntityId());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELCATEGORYID, videoEntity.getVideoCategoryId());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELNAME, videoEntity.getVideoName());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELDESCRIPTION, videoEntity.getVideoDescription());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELPATH, videoEntity.getVideoImageThumbnail());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELPOSTERPATH, videoEntity.getVideoPosterPath());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELMOBILESMALL, videoEntity.getVideoImagePath());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELSTREAMURLLOW, videoEntity.getVideoStreamUrlLow());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELTOTALVIEWS, videoEntity.getVideoTotalViews());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELMOBILELARGE, videoEntity.getVideoImagePathLarge());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELSTREAMURLHIGH, videoEntity.getVideoStreamUrl());
        initialValues.put(CHANNELS_COLUMN_CHANNELADDEDDATE, videoEntity.getVideoAddedDate());

        db.insert(TABLE_CHANNELS, null, initialValues);
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve INSERT-per-second performance of SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android SQLite database: slow insertion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501516/android-sqlite-database-slow-insertion)

Comment: @Andrain - in a nutshell: use batch inserts instead of inserting single rows :)

Answer (score 0):

When you do not use explicit transactions, the database automatically wraps a transaction around each single SQL statement.

Using one explicit transaction for each insert does not reduce the transaction overhead.

Add a single transaction around the entire loop:

```java
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    for (...) {
        ... dbHelper.insertChannels() ...
    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Please follow same things and Let me know any doubt---

Model class :--UserInfo .class

public class UserInfo implements Serializable {
private int id;
private String name;
private String username;
private String email;
private String address;
private String street;
private String suite;
private String zipcode;
private String geo;
private Long lat;
private Long lng;
private String phone;
private String website;
private String company;
private String phnname;
private String catchPhrase;
private String bs;

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getPhnname() {
    return phnname;
}

public void setPhnname(String phnname) {
    this.phnname = phnname;
}

public String getCatchPhrase() {
    return catchPhrase;
}

public void setCatchPhrase(String catchPhrase) {
    this.catchPhrase = catchPhrase;
}

public String getBs() {
    return bs;
}

public void setBs(String bs) {
    this.bs = bs;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getSuite() {
    return suite;
}

public void setSuite(String suite) {
    this.suite = suite;
}

public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public String getGeo() {
    return geo;
}

public void setGeo(String geo) {
    this.geo = geo;
}

public Long getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(Long lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public Long getLng() {
    return lng;
}

public void setLng(Long lng) {
    this.lng = lng;
}
```

}

```
DatabaseHandler class:--


 public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements EmployeeListener {

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "info.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "info_table";
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "_name";
private static final String KEY_USER_NAME = "_username";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "_email";
private static final String KEY_ZIP_CODE = "_zipcode";
private static final String KEY_STREET = "_street";
private static final String KEY_SUITE = "_suite";
private static final String KEY_PHONE = "_phone";
private static final String KEY_WEBSITE = "_website";
private static final String KEY_COMPANY = "_company";
private static final String KEY_PHONE_NAME = "_phnname";
private static final String TAG = DataBaseHandler.class.getName();

String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_ZIP_CODE + " TEXT," + KEY_STREET + " TEXT," + KEY_SUITE + " TEXT," + KEY_PHONE + " TEXT," + KEY_PHONE_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_WEBSITE + " TEXT," + KEY_COMPANY + " TEXT)";
String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}


@Override
public void addInfo(UserInfo Info) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();
    try{
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ID, Info.getId());
        values.put(KEY_NAME,Info.getName());
        values.put(KEY_USER_NAME,Info.getUsername());
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL,Info.getEmail());
        values.put(KEY_ZIP_CODE,Info.getZipcode());
        values.put(KEY_STREET,Info.getStreet());
        values.put(KEY_SUITE,Info.getSuite());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE,Info.getPhone());
        values.put(KEY_WEBSITE,Info.getWebsite());
        values.put(KEY_COMPANY,Info.getCompany());
        values.put(KEY_PHONE_NAME,Info.getPhone());
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"getting Error"+e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public ArrayList<UserInfo> getAllInfo() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfos = null;
    try{
        userInfos = new ArrayList<UserInfo>();
        String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
        if(!cursor.isLast())
        {
            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
                userInfo.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                userInfo.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                userInfo.setUsername(cursor.getString(2));
                userInfo.setEmail(cursor.getString(3));
                userInfo.setZipcode(cursor.getString(4));
                userInfo.setStreet(cursor.getString(5));
                userInfo.setSuite(cursor.getString(6));
                userInfo.setPhone(cursor.getString(7));
                userInfo.setWebsite(cursor.getString(8));
                userInfo.setCompany(cursor.getString(9));
                userInfo.setPhnname(cursor.getString(10));
                userInfos.add(userInfo);
            }
        }
        db.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("error",e+"");
    }
    return userInfos;
}

@Override
public int getAllInfoCount() {
    int num = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    try{
        String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(QUERY, null);
        num = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        return num;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"error"+e.getMessage());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

```
 List fragment:--

 public class UserListFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = UserListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
@InjectView(R.id.mRecyclerView)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
UserInfoRecylerViewAdapter userInfoRecylerViewAdapter;
private List<UserInfo> userInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
private RequestQueue mQueue;
private Context _context;
private DataBaseHandler dataBaseHandler;
private  ArrayList<UserInfo> userInfoArrayList;


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public static UserListFragment newInstance() {
    UserListFragment fragment = new UserListFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    _context = (FragmentActivity) context;

}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.inject(view);
    userInfoArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    dataBaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    _setRecylerView();
    if (dataBaseHandler.getAllInfoCount() == 0) {
        requestData(AppConstants.BASE_URL);
    } else {
        userInfoArrayList=dataBaseHandler.getAllInfo();
        Log.v(TAG,"userInfoArrayList"+userInfoArrayList.size());
        userInfoRecylerViewAdapter.addData(userInfoArrayList);
    }
}

private void _setRecylerView() {

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    userInfoRecylerViewAdapter = new UserInfoRecylerViewAdapter(_context, userInfoList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(userInfoRecylerViewAdapter);
    RecyclerView.ItemDecoration itemDecoration =
            new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
}

private void requestData(String baseUrl) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(baseUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "getting response" + response.toString());
                    try {

                        JSONArray userInfoArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < userInfoArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject obj = userInfoArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();

                            //getting employee object parsing

                            userInfo.setId(obj.getInt("id"));
                            userInfo.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                            userInfo.setUsername(obj.getString("username"));
                            userInfo.setEmail(obj.getString("email"));
                            userInfo.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                            userInfo.setWebsite(obj.getString("website"));
                            Log.v(TAG, "getting parse response" + obj.getInt("id"));

                            //getting address object parsing

                            if (obj.has("address")) {
                                JSONObject address = obj.getJSONObject("address");
                                userInfo.setStreet(address.getString("street"));
                                userInfo.setSuite(address.getString("suite"));
                                userInfo.setZipcode(address.getString("zipcode"));
                                Log.v(TAG, "getting city" + address.getString("street"));
                                if (address.has("geo")) {
                                    JSONObject geo = address.getJSONObject("geo");
                                    userInfo.setLat(geo.getLong("lat"));
                                    userInfo.setLng(geo.getLong("lng"));
                                    Log.v(TAG, "getting geo" + geo.getLong("lat"));
                                }
                            }

                            //getting comapny object parsing

                           if (obj.has("company")){
                               JSONObject company = obj.getJSONObject("company");
                               userInfo.setPhnname(company.getString("name"));
                               userInfo.setCatchPhrase(company.getString("catchPhrase"));
                               userInfo.setBs(company.getString("bs"));
                               Log.v(TAG, "getting company" + company.getString("name"));
                           }
                            dataBaseHandler.addInfo(userInfo);

                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "getting error response" + error.toString());
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    ButterKnife.reset(this);

}
```

}

Comment: This does not answer the question.